# FieldValue.delete() can only appear at the top level of your update data - Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my database:

[image]

How can I delete key "2" in lotteryIDs under the map private? I tried this:

```
db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).updateData([
"private": ["lotteryIDs" : ["2" : FieldValue.delete()]]
])
```

And now I got the error as described in the title. Using:

```
"private/lotteryIDs/\(id)": FieldValue.delete
```

obviously did not work out well. I could not find it in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/delete-data) where they only explain how to delete top-level fields, not fields within objects.

Comment: Why do you store lotteryIDs like this? Isn't easier to use a subcollection?

Comment: @fredvanrijswijk I have no idea, I just started working with Firestore and worked with Realtime Database before. In that database this structure was needed. I know Firestore is different but I am used to structure data like this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to use a dotted field path with updateData:

```
db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).updateData([
"private.lotteryIDs.2" : FieldValue.delete()])
```

Comment: 2017-10-11 18:15:02.700376+0300 Cards V2[22095:511103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: _SwiftValue (found in field private.lotteryIDs.`2`)' I copy pasted your answer but it did not work.

Comment: Hrm.  I just double-checked and this code works for me.  Can you share the exact code you tried (as a gist or something perhaps)?

Comment: Idk, I made a new project and now it is working. Thanks :D

Comment: I was able to get this working with `db.collection("users").document(currentUser.uid).update("private.lotteryIDs.2" : FieldValue.delete())`, but not with an array. `updateData` is not a method I am seeing.